# The $ 1 $-form $ \frac{x\,\mathrm dy - y\,\mathrm dx}{x^2 + y^2} $ in polar coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have a silly question about the pullback of $ 1 $-forms. Take two smooth manifolds $ M $ and $ N $ and some smooth map $ F\colon M\to N $ between them. Take some $ 1 $-form $ \eta $ on $ N $. Suppose that with respect to some coordinates $ (y^1,\dots,y^m) $ on an open subset $ V $ of $ N $ we can write
$$
\eta{\restriction_V} = \sum_{i = 1}^m \eta_i\mathrm dy^i
$$
for some smooth functions $ \eta_1,\dots,\eta_m\colon V\to \mathbb R $.

Then
$$
F^*\eta{\restriction_{F^{-1}(V)}} = \sum_{i = 1}^m (\eta_i\circ F)\,\mathrm d(y^i\circ F)
$$
by the properties of the pullback map $ F^*\colon \Omega_N^1(V)\to \Omega_M^1(F^{-1}(V)) $.

Now, I was playing with the standard example
$$
\eta = \frac{x\,\mathrm dy - y\,\mathrm dx}{x^2 + y^2}
$$
on the manifold $ X = \mathbb R^2\setminus\{\text{non positive $ x $ semi-axis}\} $. According to Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* Example 11.28, one can find the polar coordinate expression of $ \eta $ simply by computing the pullback
$$
\eta = \mathrm{id}_X^*(\eta)
$$
under the assumption that "the coordinates on the domain of $ \mathrm{id}_X $ are polar, and the coordinates on the codomain of $ \mathrm{id}_X $ are Cartesian" (semi-quoe from Lee's book). It's not clear to me what it means.

If I compute $ \mathrm{id}_X^*(\eta) $ I obtain (see above)
$$
\mathrm{id}_X^*(\eta) = \Bigl(\frac{x}{x^2 + x^2}\circ \mathrm{id}_X\Bigr)\,\mathrm d(y\circ \mathrm{id}_X) - \Bigl(\frac{y}{x^2 + x^2}\circ \mathrm{id}_X\Bigr)\,\mathrm d(x\circ \mathrm{id}_X)
$$
which is different from the result
$$
\mathrm{id}_X^*(\eta) = \Bigl(\frac{\cos\theta}{r}\Bigr)\,\mathrm d(r\sin\theta) - \Bigl(\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\Bigr)\,\mathrm d(r\cos\theta) = \dots
$$
advocated by Lee.

What am I missing?

Comment: Let me know if my solution is correct, if so mark as the right one and upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the $1-$form

$$\omega=\frac{x\,dy+ y \, dx}{x^2+y^2}.$$

Use $x=r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta, x^2+y^2=r^2$, so you have

\begin{align}
\omega&=\frac{x\,dy+ y \, dx}{x^2+y^2}\\
&=\frac{r \cos\theta\, d(r \sin \theta)+r \sin \theta \, d(r \cos \theta)}{r^2}\\
&=\frac{2\cos\theta\sin\theta\, dr+r(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)\,d\theta}{r}
\end{align}

hope this helps!! And of course you can use the trig identity for $2\cos\theta\sin\theta$..and for $d($something$)$ you apply product rule. Lee does an example of swapping to polar I believe in chapter 14 and he does what I did.

Comment: It's not clear to me _why_ you can just substitute $ r\,\cos\theta $ for $ x $ and $ r\,\sin\theta $ for $ y $ inside $ \omega $.

Comment: @GeometriaDifferenziale that’s just by definition of swapping to polar

Comment: The point is that $d$ commutes with pullback. You're pulling back by the mapping $f(r,\theta) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. $f^*x = r\cos\theta$, and so $f^*dx = d(f^*x) = d(r\cos\theta)$, etc. You might find a number of my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile) helpful.

Comment: I think I answered myself to the question I had. I wrote a summary below hoping it would clarify what wasn't clear to me. anonymous I always fought with that definition because I find it a little sloppy. I'm trying to be pedantic here (just once in a lifetime) to really learn what is going on behind the scenes. Ted Shifrin I knew that but the $ f $ I was using in my example was the identity! It was not your $ f(r,\theta) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) $! (Btw I liked your video lecture on pullbacks, even if it didn't answer my question. I should find some time to watch some others)

Comment: @TedShifrin my answer is correct though, no?

Comment: @anonymous I didn’t check details, but it looks right. I was just adding a bit of pedantic explanation/justification.

Comment: There seems two typos in your last formula for $\omega\,:$ $$\omega=\frac{(2\cos\theta\sin\theta)\,dr+r(\cos^\color{red}{2}\theta-\sin^\color{red}2\theta)\,d\theta}{r}\,.
$$ Also: reading OP's self answer I cannot stop thinking that the real $\omega$ in question was the more classic $$\omega=\frac{x\,dy\color{red}{-}y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}\,.$$

Comment: @KurtG. youre right, corrected!

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a bit of thought I think I can answer myself. I'll do it in gory detail hoping it can be of some help to other people struggling with these ideas and most importantly with the classical notation.

Our goal is to write the $ 1 $-form
$$
\eta = \frac{x\,\mathrm dy - y\,\mathrm dx}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\mathrm dy + \frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}\mathrm dx
$$
defined on the space
$$
X = \mathbb R^2\setminus{\text{non positive $ x $ semi-axis}}
$$
with respect to the local (indeed, global) frame $ \{\mathrm dr,\mathrm d\theta\} $ induced by the coordinates $ \phi = (\phi^1,\phi^2) = (r,\theta) $ on $ X $, where
$$
\phi^{-1}\colon \left]0,+\infty\right[\times \left]-\pi,\pi\right[\xrightarrow{{\cong}} X\text{,}\qquad \phi(r,\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}r\cos\theta\\ r\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the usual polar-coordinates parametrization of $ X $.

First of all, a little comment on the notation
$$
\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\text{,}\qquad \frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2} \tag{*}\label{components}
$$
used to denote the components $ f_1,f_2\in \mathscr C^\infty(X) $ such that
$$
\eta = f_2\mathrm dy + f_1\mathrm dx\text{.}
$$
When we work with $ X $ we always have in mind the chart $ (X,\epsilon) $ where $ \epsilon\colon X\to X $ is just the identity. Then we will denote with $ x $ the component $ \epsilon^1\colon X\to \mathbb R $ and with $ y $ the component $ \epsilon^2\colon X\to \mathbb R $ so that
$$
x(a,b) = \epsilon^1(a,b) = a\text{,}\qquad y(a,b) = \epsilon^2(a,b) = b
$$

for every point $ p = (a,b)\in X $. At this point we have two ways to look at $ \eqref{components} $: they can be thought of as the usual sloppy way "$ f(x) $" to denote the function $ f $ as employed in most elementary treatments; or they can be thought as a quotient in the algebra $ \mathscr C^\infty(X) $ of smooth functions $ X\to \mathbb R $ of the functions $ x $ and $ y $ defined above. This second viewpoint is the one we will employ here.

Now, J. M. Lee in his book suggest that we take the pullback
$$
\mathrm{id}_X^*(\eta) = \eta
$$
of $ \eta $ by the identity map $ \mathrm{id}_X\colon X\to X $ under the assumption that in the expression $ \mathrm{id}_X\colon X\to X $ the first $ X $ is equipped with the coordinates $ \phi = (\phi^1,\phi^2) = (r,\theta) $, while the second is equipped with the standard coordinates $ (x,y) $.

Consider then the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>\mathrm{id}_X>> X\\
@V{\phi = (r,\theta)}VV @VV{\epsilon = (x,y)}V\\
\left]0,+\infty\right[\times \left]-\pi,\pi\right[ @>\widehat{\mathrm{id}_X}>> X
\end{CD}
$$
where at the bottom there is the coordinate expression of $ \mathrm{id}_X $ with respect to the given choice of coordinates. Then
$$
\widehat{\mathrm{id}_X} = \phi^{-1}\qquad\leadsto \qquad \mathrm{id_X} = \phi^{-1}\circ \phi
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{id}_X^*(\eta) = \Bigl(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\circ \phi^{-1}\circ \phi\Bigr)\,\mathrm d(y\circ \phi^{-1}\circ\phi) + \Bigl(\frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}\circ \phi^{-1}\circ\phi\Bigr)\,\mathrm d(x\circ \phi^{-1}\circ\phi)\text{.}
$$

Let's pause for a moment and examine the expression
$$
\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\circ \phi^{-1}\circ \phi\text{.}
$$
For example let's take some $ p = (a,b)\in X $ and let's evaluate the above function at $ p $. We obtain
$$
\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\circ \phi^{-1}\circ \phi(a,b) = \frac{\cos\theta(a,b)}{r(a,b)}
$$
so that we can write simply
$$
\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\circ \phi^{-1}\circ \phi = \frac{\cos\theta}{r}
$$
(remember the second point of view advocated above; here $ \cos\theta $ is really a *composition* of functions).

At this point we're ready to conclude that
$$
\mathrm{id}_X^*(\eta) = \frac{\cos\theta}{r}\,\mathrm d(r\sin \theta) - \frac{\sin\theta}{r}\,\mathrm d(r\cos \theta) = \mathrm d\theta
$$
as it should be.

Comment: Typos all over the place: Title of OP has $\frac{x\,dy\,\color{red}{+}\,y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}\,.$ In this answer your goal is to do something with the one-form $\eta=\frac{x\,dy\,\color{red}{-}\,y\,dx}{x^2\color{red}{-}y^2}$ which miraculously turns into $\frac{x}{x^2\color{red}{+}y^2}\,dy-\frac{y}{x^2\color{red}{+}y^2}\,dx.$ Here I stop reading.

Comment: Ok I corrected all those annoying typos. The form in question is exactly the classic
$$
\eta=\frac{x\,dy\color{red}{-}y\,dx}{x^2\color{red}{+}y^2}\,\text{.}
$$

Comment: Good! While pull-back gymnastics is important I also think that you should give tribute to anonymous' answer and apply anonymous' approach to the classic. You should get $d\theta\,.$ It helps to know the simple tricks. :)